# tmux's extraneous visual bells in iTerm2

Tags: iterm, tmux

I recently started using `tmux`, I rely on visual bells (see Preferences -> Appearance -> Tabs -> Show new-output indicator) in `iTerm2` to let me know when processes start/finish.  When I start a `tmux` session in a tab of an `iTerm2` window and then change focus, after a minute or two, the 'blue dot' appears in the tab. Nothing has happened in that window. I suspect that this is due to some behind the scenes activity (e.g. keeping the session alive?)

Question :

1. How do I keep visual bells in `iTerm2` while stopping `tmux` from issuing these extraneous bells?